# How to give items for tagged people?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a mansion and as the main center piece I wanted it to be a fighting pit, I have it set up as there are two teams, one being red and the other is blue. The way people are chosen for a team is through the tag command. I was wondering how to give a tagged player an item using commands. For example: one player may be disadvantaged so I want to give the player with the tag 'red' a diamond sword.

I'm playing on the latest version on PS4.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple just do `/give @a[tag=<tag name>] ...` This will give the item to all players with the tag